# Recursive file download with wget not working

Tags: wget

From what I can tell by studying the wget manual, the following should work:

```
wget -r -l1 -np -nd -A.* -R "index.html*" http://s3.amazonaws.com/gp.gms/blat/
```

However, instead of getting all of the files in the blat folder without the apparently auto-generated `index.html` file, I get a 404 not found error on this and several dozen variations that I've tried.
I can easily download any of the 4 files but trying to do it recursively fails.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `-r -l1` with `-r -l 1`. You need a space between the `l` and the `1`. Also, try adding `-k` with your options. This will convert the links to point to the corresponding files on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the results were that the html file was rejected and the "-k" option returned "Converted links in 0 files in 0 seconds." So, still no joy but, thank you for trying.